# I have emulator problems with vt-d

Tags: virtualization

I have enabled vt-d on my BIOS, disabled core isolation and also hyper-v is disabled but its showing i did not enabled vt on nox app player and all other emulators. Even its showing my cpu vt is enabled on nox player system information. what will i do now?

i have given all screenshot of my pboblems here:https://plus.google.com/collection/8_zVmE. please review that images and give me solution.

my system config is:
MotherBoard: Gigabyte H110M-DS2
CPU: intel pentium G4400 (2 CORES)
OS: WINDOWS 10 pro(1809) latest version

ALL MY SCREENSHOTS ARE HERE:https://plus.google.com/collection/8_zVmE

Comment: Try to disable the hypervisor with command as admin: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`.

Comment: I'm not sure you're aware that you can use only one core for virtualization - the CPU is a dual core without hypertreading - so I'm here mentioning it just in case. Now, what is the problem exactly? If it works you can ignore the red error message showed in the first screenshot. Yes, it's misleading but probably just an insignificant "bug".

Comment: actually i play pubg mobile on "tencent gamming buddy" emulator. but it lags a lot and freez. when i search in web , i found these lags and freez of game is happening for my VT. but i checked my vt is turned on 
Even after all emulators saying my vt is disabled.